# Синтаксический анализатор (построение грамматики) ?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, парсер

Нужно построить синтаксический анализатор. В частности для языка создать  контекстно-зависимую грамматику( LL) Везде встречаются примеры только для чисел и знаков, у меня присутствуют только 4 буквы(A, B, C, D)  и для них надо построить грамматику .
Есть ли примеры построения грамматики ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80) не плохой пример. Грамматика это просто набор правил. Таблица синтаксического анализа лишь отражает порядок применения этих правил.

Comment: я уже давно кое в чем разобрался, но спасибо)